# show extra columns where group has count of 1

Tags: sql, group-by, count, subquery, window-functions

Suppose I have a table `Students` with just 2 columns `LastName` and `FirstName`.  I know I can get all the `LastName`s that only have a 1 `FirstName` with:

```
select LastName from Students group by LastName having count(*) = 1
```

But what if I also want to show the FirstName for those rows?

Comment: Have you tried just including firstname in your select statement like this:
select LastName, FirstName from Students group by LastName having count(*) = 1

Comment: @LemuelBotha, you can't include a column that's not an aggregate function or not in the group by columns

Comment: Oh yes, you're right

Answer (score 2):

You could filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select s.* 
from students s
where (select count(*) from students s1 where s1.LastName = s.LastName) = 1
```

Or, if you have a primary column, you can use `not exists`:

```
select s.*
from student s
where not exists (
    select 1 from students s1 where s1.LastName = s.LastName and s1.id <> s.id
)
```

This query would take advantage of an index on `(id, LastName)`.

Finally, another common option is to do a window count:

```
select *
from (select s.*, count(*) over(partition by LastName) cnt from students s) t
where cnt = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
Select * from Students where lastname in (Select lastname from Students group by lastname having count(*) =1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to the `select`:

```
select s.LastName, min(s.firstname)
from Students s
group by s.LastName
having count(*) = 1;
```

If only one row matches, then `min()` returns the value on that row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get it using any aggregate function that can return the desired value. Min, Max, first_value(), ir string_agg() you may want all names with the lastname in other use case

```
select LastName, 
first_value(firstname) over (order by firstname) firstname,
Min(firstname)
from Students 
group by LastName having count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another one myself:

```
with LastNames as (
  select LastName from Students group by LastName having count(*) = 1
)
select LastName, FirstName from Students
  where LastName in (select LastName from LastNames)
```